# How to make vim close pdf opened in evince?

Tags: vim, latex

I've added the following line to my vimrc which makes vim run latexmk on tex file I open in latex:

au BufWinEnter *.tex :Latexmk

(:Latexmk comes from the Latex Box vim plugin)

How can I add something similar that will close the pdf file and kill latexmk after I close vim? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
:au BufDelete <buffer> :!killall evince
```

Would work **if** you only use evince for preview purposes. Also, it may kill other stuff named evince. This actually kills it when you close the file. Use

```
:au VimLeave :!killall evince
```

if you want to close the apps with vim.